# cftextarea richtext editor not working in IE10

Tags: coldfusion, internet-explorer-10, fckeditor

I am having issues with `<cftextarea>` with `richtext="true"` in IE10. The problem is that `<cftextarea>` uses FCK Editor which appears to be incompatible with IE10.

It is going to be a huge job reworking this using CK Editor (which would be my first choice). Does anyone know how to force the built-in ColdFusion rich text editor to be compatible with IE10?

I have tried editing the `fckeditor.js` and `fckutils.cfm` file so that it takes into account the IE10 version number using two digits. However, these files do not seem to be being picked up/used by the cftextarea instance that I am using. However, the `fckeditor.html` file is being hit.

The changes I made to `fckeditor.js`:

```
// Internet Explorer 5.5+
if ( /*@cc_on!@*/false && sAgent.indexOf("mac") == -1 )
{
    //var sBrowserVersion = navigator.appVersion.match(/MSIE (.\..)/)[1] ;
    var sBrowserVersion = navigator.appVersion.match(/MSIE ([\d.]+)/)[1] ;
    return ( sBrowserVersion >= 5.5 ) ;
}
```

The changes I made in fckutils.cfm

```
// check for Internet Explorer ( >= 5.5 )
if( find( "msie", sAgent ) and not find( "mac", sAgent ) and not find( "opera", sAgent ) )
{
    // try to extract IE version
    stResult = reFind( "msie ([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)", sAgent, 1, true );
    if( arrayLen( stResult.pos ) eq 2 )
    {
        // get IE Version
        sBrowserVersion = mid( sAgent, stResult.pos[2], stResult.len[2] );
        if( sBrowserVersion GTE 5.5 )
            isCompatibleBrowser = true;
    }
}
```

For the `cftextarea` FCK Editor instance, should I be making any other changes somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by using the ajaxonload() function in coldfusion.

Comment: Just HOW did ajaxonload fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was completely unable to get this to work with IE 10 in CF9. I tried the changes you suggested, but there were several other JavaScript errors on IE10.

The problem is that CF is using an old version of [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) (still going by the original name FCKEditor). You might want to try downloading the latest version of CKEditor and using them in your project. That is what I did, and I found it pretty easy to implement. Basically you just include ckeditor.js in a script tag, then give any `<textarea>` tag a `class="ckeditor"` attribute, and the library takes care of everything else for you.

Obviously this is a lot easier if you use a common component to generate your text fields. If you have random `<cftextarea>` tags all over the place you will have to do a much bigger search/replace.

You could also try updating the library in CFIDE, but that might lead to more problems than it is worth.